# Conflict between label rotation and label background in SLD Style

Tags: sld, rotate

When I use rotation attribute and Graphic for label Background together in SLD Style, then SLD style ignores my rotation attribute and because of that positioning of labels is incorrect.

EXAMPLE OF MY CODE

```
 <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>D_Laybel</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>label_style_group</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>plain_text</ogc:Literal>
             
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
            <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke"> 
                <ogc:PropertyName>fme_color_hex</ogc:PropertyName>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
              <ogc:PropertyName>line_width</ogc:PropertyName>
              </CssParameter>    
            </Stroke> 
          </LineSymbolizer>
              <TextSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
              
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>label</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">
                 <ogc:Add>
               <ogc:PropertyName>font_size</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Add>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight"> </CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
                <AnchorPoint>
                  <AnchorPointX>0</AnchorPointX>
                  <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
                </AnchorPoint>
                <Displacement>
                  <DisplacementX>0</DisplacementX>
                  <DisplacementY>0</DisplacementY>
                </Displacement>
                <Rotation><ogc:PropertyName>rotation</ogc:PropertyName></Rotation>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill"><ogc:PropertyName>fme_color_hex</ogc:PropertyName></CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                 <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                 <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#eeeeee</CssParameter>                  
                 </Fill>
                 
               </Mark>
            </Graphic>
                <VendorOption name="graphic-resize">stretch</VendorOption>                         
                <VendorOption name="graphic-margin">2</VendorOption>    
              <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Comment: please add a picture of the output

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works